# Proof for the asymptotic correlation coefficient $\lim_{x\to\infty} \rho_{{\hat{\beta_0}},{\hat{\beta_1}}} = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Tags: statistics, proof-explanation, linear-regression

Be my regression model:
$$Y_i = 1 + X_i + \epsilon_i, \hspace{5mm} \epsilon_i \sim N(0,1), \hspace{5mm} X_i = \frac{i-1}{n-1}, \;\;\; i = 1, 2, ..., n$$
I want to prove that the asymptotic correlation coefficient equals:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \rho_{{\hat{\beta_0}},{\hat{\beta_1}}} = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Hints: $\begin{cases}
           S_{xx} = \frac{n(n+1)}{12(n-1)} \\
                 \sum\limits_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \\
                 \sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
        \end{cases}$

Comment: Welcome! What is $x$? What do you mean by "asymptotic correlation coefficient"?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. x is defined in the body of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formulas below to obtain $\rho_{{\hat{\beta_0}},{\hat{\beta_1}}}=\frac{\operatorname{cov}\left(\hat{\beta_0},\hat{\beta_1}\right)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}\left(\hat{\beta_0}\right)\cdot \operatorname{Var}\left(\hat{\beta_1}\right)}}$. Since  $\epsilon_i \sim N(0,1)$ it follows that $\sigma^2=1$

> $$\operatorname{Var}\left(\hat{\beta_0}\right)=\frac{\sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}{n\sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_i-\bar{x}\right)^2}$$
>
> $$\operatorname{Var}\left(\hat{\beta_1}\right)=\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_i-\bar{x}\right)^2}$$
>
> and
>
> $$\operatorname{cov}\left(\hat{\beta_0},\hat{\beta_1}\right)=\frac{-\sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{n\sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_i-\bar{x}\right)^2}$$

If we look at the formula of $\rho_{{\hat{\beta_0}},{\hat{\beta_1}}}$ we see that  $\sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_i-\bar{x}\right)^2$ are cancelling out. With the formulas of the hints it is straigtforward to calculate the limit of $\rho_{{\hat{\beta_0}},{\hat{\beta_1}}}$. Feel free to ask if something is still unclear.

Comment: Yeah, I used the variances of the estimators to put into the correlation formula, but in another form:   
$Var[\hat{\beta_0}] = \sigma^2(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{\bar{x}}{S_{xx}})\\$   
$Var[\hat{\beta_1}] = \frac{\sigma^2}{S_{xx}}$.
For the covariance I used the form:   
$Cov[\hat{\beta_0}, \hat{\beta_1}] = -\frac{\sigma^2\bar{x}}{S_{xx}}$

I must did some mistake, because I can't get the result.
Thank you for the answer. I'm gonna make the exercise again!

Comment: @igorkf It seems that your formula for $Var[\hat \beta_0]$ is not right. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2957224/144421) It is $\overline x^2$ instead of $\overline x$

Comment: Yes, you're right.
I just miswrited here in stack. Sorry.

Comment: @igorkf Do you have any further questions? If not please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark $\left(\color{\limegreen}{\checkmark}\right)$